# Is there a way to use a user input as a default value for a function?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Pine Script shows this error:
"Cannot use 'i_int' as the default value of a type's field. The default value cannot be a function, variable or calculation."
for this script:

```
i_int = input.int(100, "test input")
f1(x = i_int) => x
```

I only came to a trick of using an improbable default value (e.g. -999999) so that the function could then use a user input value in its place.

Answer (score 0):

Official answer from support:

"The normal way, in this case, would be declaring the default value directly in the function's declaration, custom variables could not be used as defaults, and there is no workaround, unfortunately."

My workaround (works 100% if there is any impossible value):

```
var DEFAULT_VALUE = "default_value"

f(x = "<improbable_value>") =>

    _x == "improbable_value" ? DEFAULT_VALUE : x
```